# Export image to Drive error

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sentinel-2

I'm trying to export only one class from a classification:

```js
var vegetation = classificacao.eq(2);

Map.addLayer(vegetation, {
    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    palette: ['white', 'black']
}, 'Vegetation');
print(Vegetation);

Export.image.toDrive({
    image: vegetation,
    folder: 'Class_2',
    description: 'class',
    maxPixels: 1e13,
    region: roi,
    scale: 10,
})
```

But this error appears:

```
Unknown element type provided: undefined. Expected: ee.Image,
ee.ImageCollection, ee.FeatureCollection, ee.Element or
ee.ComputedObject.
```

Comment: Add a link to failing script (or the whole script).  There's not enough info here to debug.